# Як перекласти з англійської «letter case»?

Tags: переклад, from-english, терміни, іменники, типографіка

В контексті літер, ***case*** — це те, **є літера великою чи малою**. Наприклад:

- *upper-case [letter]* — «велика [літера]»;
- *lower-case [letter]* — «мала [літера]».

Очевидно, що мене цікавлять не прикметники *upper-case* і *lower-case*, а сам іменник *case* (в контексті великості-малості літер) — як українською передати саму оцю характеристику (чи є літера великою чи малою).

<sub>Наприклад:</sub>

- <sub>*Letters have two cases: upper and lower.* → «Літери мають два можливі <чого саме?>: великий і малий.»</sub>
- <sub>*Letter case is coded using one bit.* → «*<Що саме?>* літери кодується одним бітом.»</sub>
- <sub>*Different cases of a letter can diverge visually.* → «Різні *<що?>* літери можуть суттєво відрізнятися візуально.»</sub>

---

Мою першою спробою було: «**регістр**». Спочатку мені здалося, що це усталений термін, принаймні в контексті комп'ютерних систем («літери мають два регістри: великий і малий»). Але подивишись [значення цього слова в «Словнику української мови»](http://sum.in.ua/s/reghistr), я побачив, що регістр — це список (перелік) чи набір чогось, або розподільник чи регулятор у приладах. Ймовірно, «регістр літери» є невдалою спробою перенесення поняття «регістр *клавіатури* (друкарської машинки абощо)», де воно позначало **увесь набір** (великих чи малих) літер. Тому, відповідно, вираз «літера у верхньому регістрі» має сенс (наприклад, «літера „А“ у верхньому регістрі [певної друкарської машинки] виглядає так-то»), але фраза «великий регістр *літери*» (наприклад, «великий регістр літери „А“ виглядає так-то») — ні.

---

Тож питання: яким іменником чи групою слів (у ролі іменника) можна передати це поняття / цю характеристику (великість-чи-малість) **по відношенню до однієї літери**?

За можливості, мене цікавить більше нейтральна лексика (а не професіоналізми).

Comment: Насправді, англійське "lower case" означає "набірна каса з малими літерами" (що використовувалася у докомп'ютерну епоху у друкарнях), тобто походження "регістр" від друкарської машинки не повинно вважатися чимось поганим. [Переклад поліграфічних термінів із словом case](http://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?a=3&&s=case&sc=104&l1=1&l2=2)

Comment: @Artemix, я не про те, що воно походить від друкарської машинки, а про те, що воно позначає **всю множину літер** (друкарської машинки, клавіатури тощо), а не **підвид-за-розміром однієї літери**. Можливо, англійське *case* оригінально мало те саме значення, але, тим не менше, зараз англійське *case* закріпилося в тому числі в застосуванні до однієї літери. Наскільки правильно вживати регістр у застосуванні до однієї літери — питання відкрите (в словниках такого значення нема, інших доказів я теж не бачу).

Comment: @Artemix, це не важливо, які інші значення має слово *case*. Воно закріпилося як «each of the two forms, capital or minuscule». (Можливо, цьому сприяли загальні значення *case*, такі як «випадок», «трапляння», «зразок», а не лише «коробка» — я не знаю.)

Comment: @Artemix, «верблюжий регістр» — трішки не те. По-перше, це сталий вираз (без слова «верблюжий», «регістр» не факт, що не втрачає такий відтінок значення). По-друге, це трішки інший відтінок значення — це стиль написання тексту в цілому (а не підвид однієї літери — хоча можна вважати це гіперонімом). По-третє, це професіональний сленґ, а я шукаю, за можливості, нейтральне слово (сполучення).

Comment: @Sasha, якщо ви шукаєте нейтральний іменник, то мені здається, підходить **положення**, відповідно **верхнє положення**, **нижнє положення**. І мені дуже дивно, що воно не використовується, а використовується натомість "регістр". Адже, наприклад [Multitran](http://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?l1=1&l2=2&s=case) першим значенняим *case* дає саме **положение**. А одне із значень, причому перше, **положення** в [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/polozhennja) - 1. Місцезнаходження кого-, чого-небудь у просторі.

Comment: @Sasha Наскільки я пам'ятаю, *положення* використовується в аналогічному контексті для напрямку тексту (вертикальний/горизонтальний). Тому незрозуміло, чому його не можна використовувати також замість *регістру*. Напевно, тому що всі вже звикли й недоцільно замінювати усталений й широковживаний термін?

Comment: @OksanaGubrenko, це зовсім не те. Може в контексті друкарських машинок і підійде, але я шукаю загальне слово. «Верхнє положення літери „і“ виглядає схоже на нижнє положення літери „L“.» «Японські ієрогліфи не мають положень.» «Літера „Г“ має два положення, які майже не відрізняються між собою.» Щось не те…

Comment: З прикметниками "великий/малий" добре б звучало слово, яке позначало б розмір (габарити), проте важко підібрати щось однозначне, бо "розмір" вже  вживається в іншому значенні

Comment: @OlexandrMatviienko, власне, необов'язково «великий»/«малий», можна й «верхній»/«нижній», «заглавний»/«рядковий» тощо. Головне іменник. Ну, в принципі, [варіант Jack](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/1038/4) прийнятний.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Оскільки мова йде про *графічне* вираження літери (зображення), а не про [ящики](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case) чи про групу клавіш клавіатури, то потрібні нам слова, ймовірніше, мають відношення до письма.

Письмо — система графічних знаків української писемності. Цю систему ще називають *українською графікою* або просто *графікою*.

> Літери сучасної графіки бувають великі й малі. [ЕСУ](http://esu.com.ua/search_articles.php?id=26852)

> З. В. Партико вважає, що графіка – це сукупність усіх символів, які
>   використовують у певний час у писемному мовленні якоїсь мови. До
>   складу графіки входять пробіл, розділові знаки, арабські і римські
>   цифри, апостроф, знак наголосу, а також інші допоміжні знаки [Партико
>   2008, с. 56].
>
> [Графічні особливості англійських засобів масової комунікації, стор. 3](http://esnuir.eenu.edu.ua/bitstream/123456789/1061/3/majaruk_graf.pdf)

Як бачимо, під графікою розуміють усі символи. Але чи можна використати це слово в контексті щодо однієї літери? Деякі знайдені зразки вказують, що так:

> Тут схожі і **графіка літери** М, на відміну від інших шрифтів, і
>   подібність обох літер Р.
>
> Тут і близькі пропорції (віленський шрифт більш квадратний, порівняно
>   з празьким), і дуже схожа **графіка окремих літер**...
>   [Блог «Кирилівські читання».](http://cyreading.blogspot.com/2012/05/blog-post_18.html)

> Звертає увагу **графіка літери** Ж — значно збільшеного розміру порівняно
>   з іншими літерами у слові...
>
> [В. В. Панашенко. Палеографія українського скоропису другої половини
>   XVII ст., стор. 52.](http://shron.chtyvo.org.ua/Panashenko_VV/Paleohrafia_ukrainskoho_skoropysu.pdf)

У наших прикладах, якщо: *«Літера має дві можливі графіки: велику і малу».* — ще так-сяк, то: *«Велика графіка літери А, мала графіка літери м»* здається, нікуди не годиться. Конструкція *«Графіка великої літери А, графіка малої літери м»* видається правильнішою.

Далі:

> *[Українська графіка](http://online-hw.com/content/s_t-pravila/grafika.html)* – це сукупність **начертальних** знаків (писаних, друкованих, мальованих), вживаних для писемного відтворення
>   мовлення.

Крім того, графікою називають складову графічної лінгвістики:

> На думку С. І. Дорошенка *графіка* – (від грец. graphikos- „письмовий‟,
>   „намальований‟, „зображений‟) – це розділ науки про письмо, яка вивчає
>   різні системи вироблених протягом історії письмових або друкованих
>   знаків, особливості їх форм, систему додаткових (розпізнавальних,
>   діакритичних) позначок. **Графіка встановлює відмінності начертання
>   літер навіть в алфавіті однієї мови, зокрема написання великих і малих
>   букв**, зображення друкованих і рукописних літер [Дорошенко 2006, с.
>   264].
>
> [Графічні особливості англійських засобів масової комунікації, стор. 3](http://esnuir.eenu.edu.ua/bitstream/123456789/1061/3/majaruk_graf.pdf)

Отже, використовується слово *начертання*. При цьому, як написано вище, не має значення як, власне, технічно здійснюється начертання знаків.

[СУМ:](http://sum.in.ua/s/nachertannja)

> **НАЧЕРТА́ННЯ**, я, сер.
>
> Зовнішня форма, зображення чого-небудь.
>
> *Теорія алфавіту вивчає склад букв, їх начертання, загальний стиль і т. п.* (Словник лінгвістичних термінів, 1957, 11).

Спробуємо вжити у наших прикладах:

- *«Літера має два можливі начертання: велике і мале»*
- *«Начертання літери кодується одним бітом»*
- *«Літера „Г“ має два начертання, які майже не відрізняються між собою»*

Думаю, непогано. А як щодо цього:

*«Велике начертання літери „А“ виглядає так-то, а мале начертання цієї літери ось так».*

Годиться?

Поряд з ним, розповсюджено вживається ідентичне слово **накреслення**, яке використовується в тому ж сенсі. Хоча [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/nakreslennja) не подає для нього такого означення.

> Сучасне **накреслення** літер укр. писем. графіки сформоване на основі
>   давньорус. письма, а друкованих – на основі рос. гражданського шрифту. [ЕСУ](http://esu.com.ua/search_articles.php?id=26852)

*«Велике накреслення літери „А“ виглядає так-то»*

[Google](https://www.google.com.ua/search?num=50&espv=2&q=%22%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F%22) навіть видає два результати, в яких вживається це словосполучення "велике накреслення" (тоді як для "велике начертання" вони взагалі відсутні):

> ... кеглів і накреслень всередині кожної гарнітури, пряме, курсивне,
>   світле, напівжирне, **мале та велике накреслення букв**, а також жирне,...
>
> [Шевченко В. Мультимедійний контент: конспект лекцій.](https://issuu.com/victoryshe/docs/multimedia_conspect_final)

> Рекомендується використовувати **велике накреслення літер**, висота
>   повинна бути більшою за інші написи на обкладинці.
>
> [Картографічне креслення та комп'ютерна графіка.](http://www.geo.univ.kiev.ua/images/doc_file/navch_lit/metod_dizayn-3.doc)

Втім, що заважає замість цих слів використати всім знайоме слово **написання** (хоча, знову ж таки, СУМ не дає такого означення цього слова):

*«Велике написання літери „А“ виглядає так-то».*

Єдиний недолік вищезгаданих слів, в тому, що вони мають дещо загальний сенс: ними також описують стиль, контрастність шрифту (світле, жирне, пряме, похиле і т.д. начертання/накреслення/написання).

Comment: Дуже добре! Щось таке й очікував. Шкода, що «начертання»/«(на)креслення»/«написання» мають багато змістів (тобто під ними можуть матися на увазі й звичайний/напівжирний/курсив, а не «велика»/«мала») — але ідеального нічого не буває.

Answer (score 4):

Якщо шукати "нейтральний" термін, що не має "спеціального" походження, то для більшості людей-неспеціалістів достатньо того що є "великі" і "малі" літери. Абстрагувати цю відмінність окремим словом для звичайного вжитку (тобто для пересічного користувача) немає ніякого сенсу. Навіть у правописі це поняття не абстраговане.

Отже, намагаючись знайти абстрактне поняття ми з необхідністю виходимо за межі "мовної нейтральності".

З огляду на це, **максимально нейтральне** вживання вказаних прикладів буде:

- «Літери бувають двох розмірів: великі і малі».
- «Велика чи мала літера - кодується одним бітом».
- «Великі і малі літери можуть суттєво відрізнятися візуально».

Приклад використання - юридичний документ, де пояснюєтся чи є різними назви підприємств в яких вказані великі і малі літери:

- [Журнал Дебет-Кредит](https://online.dtkt.ua/Book/%C2%AB%D0%94%D0%9A%C2%BB%20%E2%84%9604-2013.epub/navPoint-11) Таким чином, найменування юридичної особи, написане великими буквами, є тотожним найменуванню юридичної особи, написаному великими та малими буквами, якщо ці букви повністю збігаються. (Лист Держкомпідприємництва)

---

Стаття щодо алфавіту пропонує слово "форма":

- Стаття Український алфавіт [Літопис](http://litopys.org.ua/ukrmova/um124.htm), [Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0): Літери У. а. за **формою** бувають великі й малі, а за різновидом — друковані й писані.

На мій погляд слово "форма" погано передає відмінність між великими і малими літерами:

- «Літери бувають двох форм: великі і малі».
- «Форма літери кодується одним бітом».
- «Літери різних форм можуть суттєво відрізнятися візуально».

---

Тепер, з огляду того що всі, хто стикаються з великими і малими літерами, роблять це переважно на комп'ютері, давайте подивимося як викручуються програмісти з цієї проблеми (шукав "зміна великих літер на малі"):

- [Форум Delphi](http://replace.org.ua/topic/1826/): Замінити усі малі букви на великі, а великі на малі. Не використовувати вбудовану функцію для зміну **регістру**.
- [Microsoft Office](https://support.office.com/uk-ua/article/%D0%97%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83-1d86cf80-fbef-4380-8d6f-59a6b77db749): Змінення регістра. Щоб змінити регістр виділеного тексту в документі, виконайте такі дії ... Виберіть із розкривного списку один із варіантів, серед яких Як у реченнях, усі малі, УСІ ВЕЛИКІ, Кожне Слово З Великої та зМІНИТИ рЕГІСТР.
- [Google](https://support.google.com/adwords/editor/answer/56358?hl=uk): Зміна використання великих літер у тексті. Виберіть варіант використання великих літер у тексті. 
  Регістр заголовка: з великої літери пишеться кожне слово (наприклад, "Мій Заголовок Оголошення").
  Регістр речення: з великої літери пишеться лише перше слово кожного рядка (наприклад, "Мій заголовок оголошення").
  Нижній регістр: великі літери не використовуються; усі слова пишуться з малої (наприклад, "мій заголовок оголошення").
- [Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%94%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%88): ⇧ Shift + «буква/цифра з ряду над буквами» — **змінити регістр літери** (залежно від стану ⇪ Caps Lock); для цифри — використовувати символ, розміщений на клавіші;
  ⇪ Caps Lock — включення режиму «великих літер» (загоряється індикатор);

Цікаво, що перші три посилання оперують із сукупностями літер (реченнями), а Вікіпедія прямо називає цю абстракцію "регістром літери".

<sub>Насправді, англійське "lower case" означає "набірна каса з малими літерами" (що використовувалася у докомп'ютерну епоху у друкарнях), тобто походження "регістр" від друкарської машинки не повинно вважатися чимось поганим. [Переклад поліграфічних термінів із словом case](http://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?a=3&&s=case&sc=104&l1=1&l2=2): "music-type case" - каса для музичних знаків, "compositor's case" - набірна каса, "case room" - набірний цех, "case cleaner" - пристрій для очищення літер у касі, "space case" - каса для шпацій (прогаликів?). [Набірна каса](http://vseslova.com.ua/word/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B0_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%96%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0-45234u).</sub>
<sub>Стиль оформлення назв у програмуванні (вікіпедія): [Верблюжий регістр](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80) (ще є статті "зміїний регістр" та "шашличний регістр").</sub>

Спробуємо "регістр":

- «Існує два регістри літер: великий і малий».
- «Регістр літери кодується одним бітом».
- «Літери різних регістрів можуть суттєво відрізнятися візуально».

Мені ці фрази здаються досить природними.

Щодо "кодування одним бітом" - це взагалі очевидно комп'ютерна лексика і "регістр" тут з огляду на всі вищенаведені посилання вписується просто ідеально.

**UPD:** Відповідь на питання "чи можна сказати: «літера „Г“ має два регістри...»?".

З усіх прикладів вживання "регістру" і "літер" видно що регістр — це множина літер. Тобто не літера має регістри, а *регістр складається з літер*. Отже треба сказати:

- «Літера "Г" обох регістрів майже не відрізняється».

<sub>Думаю що і в англійській upper-case letter теж спершу означало "літера з верхнього case".</sub>

---

Тепер щодо відповіді Jack: недолік, який він згадує - принциповий.

Проблема з накресленням/начертанням в тому що це термін:

> [Накреслення шрифту](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D1%88%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%82%D1%83) (Typeface)
>   Існує 5 типів зміни накреслення, які залежать від того, що саме і як змінюється в символі:
>
> - за нахилом і характером вічка: пряме, похиле, курсив.
> - за насиченістю: світлі, суперсвітлі, напівжирні, жирні.
> - за щільністю: стиснуті, нормальні, широкі.
> - за заповненістю: контурні, відтінені, заштриховані.
> - за модифікацією тексту: нижнє підкреслення, одинарне або подвійне закреслення, зсув під або над базову лінію шрифту.

Тобто загальновживані види шрифтів (нормальні, напівжирні, курсив) - всі підпадають під означення "накреслення". (А насправді це комбінація: може бути курсивний світлий стиснутий шрифт "Segoe UI Light Italic Condensed").

Тепер дивимося на приклади використання:

> - «Літера має два можливі начертання: велике і мале»

Добре, хай буде ще "велике" і "мале". Що робити с курсивом? Він вже не можливий?

> - «Начертання літери кодується одним бітом»

З контексту зовсім не зрозуміло чи буде це нормальний/напівжирний чи підкреслений/курсив.

> - «Літера „Г“ має два начертання, які майже не відрізняються між собою»

З контексту не зрозуміло чому "г" не відрізняється від *"г"*

На мій погляд "графічні" слова (що концентруються на формі, малюнку, контурах і т.і. літери) - вони усі опиняються у ситуації коли неможливо розрізнити різні графічні форми літер в одному шрифті.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55406/discussion-between-artemix-and-sasha).